# Making nulls into blank strings

Tags: coldfusion, null, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I want to treat nulls as blanks in a section of code. `Bootstrap.actionRoot` often does not exist.

I want to be able to do something like

```
body.replacelist("~/", Bootstrap?.actionRoot)
```

OR

```
body.replacelist("~/", "#Bootstrap?.actionRoot#")
```

But it wont work because `Bootstrap?.actionRoot` is null. Is there a single statement approach to deal with this.

Comment: Check the existence and the length separately. You can't do it in one check. Unfortunately this isn't like groovy

Comment: cfparam is such an easy tag to use.

Comment: The issue with `<cfparam>` is that it changes `Bootstrap.actionRoot`. I was hoping `?.` could eminate `<cfparam>`. Maybe this is a case where it can't